# Upload binary data using box api

Tags: php, box-api

Is it possible to upload binary content using the Box API? Is it possible to upload a file from a remote server by sending an HTTP URL to the Box API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking if you can upload a binary file, like a zip file, .exe file, or a jpg/gif/mp3 file.

Of course you can.  What good would a file-sharing service be if you couldn't?

As for your 2nd question, can you upload from a remote server.  Generally no.

Comment: Why the HTML5 comment? I don't see why that's relevant.

Comment: Because more and more we're seeing that people want to just get a PDF or word doc converted to HTML5, since HTML5 will preview in any browser, without a plugin, in about 1/10th the time it takes to load a PDF.  HTML5 is way more bandwidth considerate.

Comment: I still don't see why that is relevant to either of the two questions OP asked. You still have my upvote because you answered those correctly, but I'm just confused :-)

Comment: Okay, happy to remove it.